# Emacs + Cider: Show all autocomplete options without typing first letters

Tags: emacs, clojure, autocomplete, cider

I'm trying to understand whether I'm not using cider properly or that's how it works and I have to get used to it.

Steps to reproduce:

Load the following ns/file/buffer into a running cider repl:

```
(ns app.domain)
(defn my-func [])
```

Switch to another ns via `(in-ns 'app.foo)`
then start typing `app.domain/` and it doesn't show any available options(I expect `my-func` autocompletion).

It shows `my-func` autocomplete option only after I type the first character - `m`.

Comment: I just press TAB whenever I want to get a list of symbols.

Comment: @JurajMartinka thanks for the hint! M-tab worked in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I've found:

[CIDER / Using CIDER / Code Completion](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/usage/code_completion.html#standard-completion)

> When you press TAB or M-TAB you’ll get completion candidates in a dedicated buffer.

In my case it was `M-Tab`(probably because of evil-mode?).